# du reports size for a directory 4 KBs more than the sum total of the contents

Tags: disk-usage

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1$ ls ./control
amer  calls  q1  q2  q3  quit.c  RCS  SCCS
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1$ du ./control
20  ./control/calls
16  ./control/RCS
40  ./control/SCCS
96  ./control
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1$ du ./control/*
0   ./control/amer
20  ./control/calls
4   ./control/q1
4   ./control/q2
4   ./control/q3
4   ./control/quit.c
16  ./control/RCS
40  ./control/SCCS
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1$
```

Please note `du` reports that control directory occupies 96 bytes.
Now when I add the bytes consumed by the individual files, it comes to be 92 bytes.

In the same way, for all reporting du shows 4 bytes more than the sum total of the contents.

What this extra 4 bytes from?

> EDIT#1

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1$ ls -ld $_
drwxrwxr-x 5 ravbholua ravbholua 4096 Dec  8 21:39 control
```

`du` ( or linux) uses 1024-byte blocks (1KB) for reporting (1024 * 4 = 4096) a file.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1/control$ ls
ame  amer  calls  q1  q2  q3  quit.c  RCS  SCCS
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1/control$ du ame
4   ame
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1/control$ cat ame
a
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~/CCPP/HelloWorld/das/das1/control$ ll ame
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravbholua ravbholua 2 Dec  8 21:39 ame
```

So the above file 'ame' which contains only letter 'a' and 'enter key' occupies 4 KBs of my disk space.

So that means for a file/directory linux is allocating 4KB of my disk space!!!! and it will allocate in multiples of 4KB.

Also adding one more thing: `ls -l` reports size in units of byte for a directory but not for a regular file. With ref. to the above file 'ame', its clear that for a regular file `ls -l` reports size as character count and not bytes.

Comment: Note that sizes are not in bytes. As you can read in du info page: `Normally the disk space is printed in units of 1024 bytes, but this can be overridden`

Comment: @andcoz, the space is generally printed in 512 byte units. Only some implementations like GNU or busybox use kilo-bytes (actually [kibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)) unless in POSIX/Unix compatibility mode, such as when the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set).

Comment: This is normal. Disks are handled a large number of sectors, not as an even larger number of bytes.

Answer (score 7):

The `control` directory itself has size 4 and it is included in your first command. The second variant doesn't calculate the directory size because you're not passing it to `du`, but only its contents.

There is also the possibility that you have hidden files (dot-files) that are excluded when expanding the `*` glob  so that `du` doesn't bother with them.

Answer (score 1):

First, the number isn't in bytes. The unit is either kilobytes or half-kilobytes, depending on your implementation.

When you run `du ./control/*`, you get information for the files contained in the directory `control`, but not for the directory `control` itself. Directories have a size too — the information about the files they contain has to be stored somewhere. The size of `control` itself is 4 units.

Comment: I have edited my Q. Please give your confirmation on what I stated.

Comment: @Ravi The output of `ls -l` shows that your `du` implementation uses units of 1kB.